# ismounted antipattern, track own property

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactJs, after reading this part of the docs:

> An easy migration strategy for anyone upgrading their code to avoid
>   isMounted() is to track the mounted status yourself. Just set a
>   _isMounted property to true in componentDidMount and set it to false in componentWillUnmount, and use this variable to check your
>   component's status.

Does that mean the `_isMounted` value has to be stored in `state`?

I have this so far:

```
isMounted: function(){
    this.setState({ _isMounted: true });
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    if(this.state._isMounted) {  // This is bad.
        this.setState({...});
    }
},
```

Comment: I actually disagree with the accepted answer and think it means, set it like `this._isMounted = true` in didMount and `... = false` in willUnmount, and then check it where you need to with `if (this._isMounted)`

Comment: @TKoL That  won't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-forest-4lf7i

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can track `_isMounted` in `state`, since:

1. It cannot be computed from props
2. You will most likely use it in `render()`

Via https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/749710501916139520

**Example**

http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/GqvyOE

**SomeComponent.jsx**

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      _isMounted: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      _isMounted: true
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { _isMounted } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        Mounted? { _isMounted ? 'Yes' : 'No' }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how to work around this antipattern as well and ended up using the accepted answer from lux.

It later turns out using state is just as bad and even causes double render.

The intended antipattern *work around* is forex:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = undefined;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this._isMounted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-forest-4lf7i It will only log undefined in `render()`

Comment: That wont yes, since the lifecycle methods arent executed before render.