# How to cancel promise in componentWillUnmount() without using this.isMounted?

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have to call API when the user stops typing and it is working perfectly fine. And I have to mount when the enter key is pressed.
I made a [Mock Component here](https://codesandbox.io/s/llkp4wvzn7) which does this.

But, when the component is unmounted it shows the error `Cannot call setState on an unmounted component`. Previously I handled this error with `this.isMounted`. Now I was trying to handle it using promise cancelling in componentWillUnmount as mentioned in the [React Blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

```js
this.cancellablePromise = makeCancelable(getSearchResults(word));

      this.cancellablePromise.promise
        .then(res => {
          console.log({ res });
          this.setState({ values: res });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("error", err));
      console.log("in data ", this.cancellablePromise);
    }
```

The cancellablePromise gets assigned after the promise got resolved. So there is a null object in componentWillUnMount for cancellablePromise instance.

Comment: What exactly does `makeCancelable` do?

Comment: You should take look at promise-based debounce like https://github.com/slorber/awesome-debounce-promise . As explained here, observables are is much more suitable suitable for such tasks, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328220/3731501 . It's a no-brainer with RxJS `debounce`.

Comment: it works if we track all promises and cancel it...

Comment: @estus Thank you i will take a look into it

Comment: Working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to do the following thing:

```
myAwesomeMethod = () => {
    this.cancellablePromise = makeCancelable(getSearchResults(word));
    this.cancellablePromise
        .then(...)
        .catch(...)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.cancellablePromise && this.cancellablePromise.cancel();
}
```

`this.cancellablePromise` will be undefined only in the case when you unmount your component before the call of the method with promise call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `handleChange` method calls `debouncedGetSearchResult`, but you are initializing `this.cancellablePromise` in `getSearchResult`. This leaves a 500ms window for the unmount to happen before you have initialized `this.cancellablePromise`.

You need to rework this so that the debouncing is part of the cancelable promise rather than prior to it.